# Add select dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form to create invoices. Going through the last entry automatically adds a new line. I have the problem that I have to add a select in each line to select the article reference (I have a function that fills the data with a query when selecting it). The question is:

-How can I make the select come out dynamically when adding each line, taking into account that it has to call the function that imports the description and the price?

Thank you

initial form

```html
<table class="table table-bordered item-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class=""></th>
      <th>Referencia</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th class="">Cantidad</th>
      <th class="">Precio</th>
      <th class="text-right">DTO</th>
      <th class="text-center">Base</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="delete-item-row">
        <ul class="table-controls">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
                <line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line>
                <line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line>
              </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      
      <td class="rate">
        <?php
          $comprobar_articulos = $Articulos->listararticulos("");
          
          if ($cliart = mysqli_fetch_array($comprobar_articulos)) {
            echo '<select id="referenciaarticulo_1" data-width="fit"  name="referenciaarticulo_1" data-i="1"  class="selectpicker form-control" data-size="3" data-live-search="true" style="width: 10px;" onchange="asignarReferencia()">';
            echo '<option value="">Busqueda</option>';
            
            do {
               echo '<option value="'.$cliart['id'].'" >'.$cliart['referencia'].$espacio_cliente.$cliart['nombre'].'</option>';
            } while ($cliart = mysqli_fetch_array($comprobar_articulos));
            
            echo '</select>';
          } else {}
        ?>
      </td>
      
      <td class="description">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Descripción" name="descripcion_1">
      </td>
      
      <td class="text-right qty">
        <input type="text" class="form-control  sumarLinea" placeholder="Cantidad" name="cantidad_1" data-i="1" id="cantidadhoras1"></td>
      
      <td class="rate">
        <input type="text" class="form-control  sumarLinea" placeholder="Precio" name="precio_1" data-i="1" id="importeporhora1">
      </td>
      
      <td class="rate">
        <input type="text" class="form-control  sumarLinea" placeholder="Dto" name="dto_1" data-i="1" id="dto1" value="0">
      </td>
      
      <td class="rate">
        <input type="text" class="form-control  sumarLinea" placeholder="Importe Total" name="importe_total_1" data-i="1" id="base1" readonly onfocus="anadir()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```js
function asignarReferencia() {
  var seleccionado = document.getElementById("referenciaarticulo_1").value;
}

function anadir() {
  var contador = document.getElementById('contador').value;
  var contador = parseInt(contador) + 1;
  $("input[name='contador']").val(contador);
  console.log("EL CONTADOR ES " + contador);
  getTableElement = document.querySelector('.item-table');
  currentIndex = getTableElement.rows.length;

  $html = '<tr style="padding: 15px">' +
    '<td class="delete-item-row">' +
    '<ul class="table-controls">' +
    '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg></a></li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class="description"><input type="text" class="form-control list="referenciaarticulo" form-control-sm" placeholder="Referencia" name="referencia' + contador + '"> </textarea></td>' +
    '<td class="description"><input type="text" class="form-control  form-control-sm" placeholder="Descripción" name="descripcion_' + contador + '"> </textarea></td>' +
    '<td class="text-right qty"><input type="text" class="form-control  form-control-sm sumarLinea" placeholder="Cantidad" name="cantidad_' + contador + '"  data-i="' + contador + '" id="cantidadhoras1"></td>' +
    '<td class="rate">' +
    '<input type="text" class="form-control  form-control-sm sumarLinea" placeholder="Precio" name="precio_' + contador + '"  data-i="' + contador + '" id="importeporhora1">' +
    ' </td>' +
    '<td class="text-right qty"><input type="text" class="form-control  form-control-sm sumarLinea" placeholder="Dto" name="dto_' + contador + '"  data-i="' + contador + '" id="dto1" value="0"></td>' +
    '<td class="text-right qty"><input type="text" class="form-control  form-control-sm sumarLinea" placeholder="Total" name="importe_total_' + contador + '"  data-i="' + contador + '" id="base1" readonly onfocus="anadir()"></td>' +
    '</tr>';

  $(".item-table tbody").append($html);
  deleteItemRow();
  var contador = document.getElementById('contador').value;
  
  if (contador != 1) {
    //Cantidad anterior
    var cantidadanterior = document.getElementById('cantidadanterior').value;
    //Sumatoria que lleva de numero de unidades2
    var sumatoria_unidades = document.getElementById('sumatoria_unidades').value;
    //Precio por unidad anterior
    var basesindtoanterior = document.getElementById('basesindtoanterior').value;
    //Sumatoria que lleva de la base sin descuento
    var sumatoria_base_sin_dto = document.getElementById('sumatoria_base_sin_dto').value;
    //Sumatoria que lleva de descuento
    var sumatoria_dto = document.getElementById('sumatoria_dto').value;
    //Importe con el descuento
    var valant = document.getElementById('valant').value;
    //Sumatoria que lleva de importe con descuento
    var impt = document.getElementById('impt').value;
    //Calculamos la base sin descuento
    var baseporcantidad = parseFloat(basesindtoanterior) * parseFloat(cantidadanterior);
    sumasindto = parseFloat(baseporcantidad) + parseFloat(sumatoria_base_sin_dto);
    textsindto = sumasindto;
    document.getElementById('totalbasesindto').innerHTML = textsindto;
    document.getElementById('sumatoria_base_sin_dto').value = textsindto;
    //Calculamos el total con el descuento
    suma = parseFloat(impt) + parseFloat(valant);
    text = suma;
    document.getElementById('totalbase').innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById('impt').value = text;
    //Calculamos el descuento
    var importe_dto = document.getElementById('importe_dto').value;
    //Descuento hecho y seteamos el campo con el valor del descuento
    $descuentohecho = parseFloat(suma) - parseFloat(sumasindto);
    //Sumamos el descuento anterior mas el numero
    sumadto = parseFloat(suma) - parseFloat(sumasindto);
    document.getElementById('importe_dto').value = $descuentohecho;
    document.getElementById('importedtosum').innerHTML = sumadto;
    //Calculamos el total mas IVA
    var tipoiva = "1.21";
    sumatotalisimo = parseFloat(suma) * parseFloat(tipoiva);
    document.getElementById('importetotalsum').innerHTML = sumatotalisimo;
  }
}
```

Comment: The function ``asignarReferencia()`` does nothing, because the var ``seleccionado`` is only accessable in that function, but not outside...

Comment: I know, that's why I wonder how to mount that select with that function when I add the line

Comment: Could it be, that your question targets the php part that is inserting the ``select`` elements?

Comment: I think not, because I know how to load it in php, what I don't know is how to make that datalist appear in the new lines that I add, and that the function that I use also works in those lines that I add

Comment: If i try your code, i get the error ``Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')`` because there is no element ``#contador``...